# Какое регулярное выражение для проверки украинского номера телефона

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

```
Только чтоб такие номера проходили: 
0991122334
80112233445
+380112233445

Такие варианты не верны:
+38011-22-33-445
+80112233445
+0112233445
380112233445
```

const regExp = /$/;

Comment: `^(\+3|)[0-9]{10,11}$`

Comment: Cпасибо большое!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Регулярное выражение, предложенное в комментарии, вероятно будет работать в лабораторных условиях (на Ваших данных), но при реальном пользовательском вводе:

```js
const test_data = ['0991122334', '80112233445', '+380112233445', '+38011-22-33-445', '+80112233445', '+0112233445', '380112233445', '+311111111111', '+38012345678', '+390123456789', '1234567890'];

const regexp = /^(\+3|)[0-9]{10,11}$/;



for (const t of test_data) {
  console.log(t, ' --- ', regexp.test(t));
}
```

По Вашему запросу регулярка такая:

```js
const test_data = ['0991122334', '80112233445', '+380112233445', '+38011-22-33-445', '+80112233445', '+0112233445', '380112233445', '+311111111111', '+38012345678', '+390123456789', '1234567890'];

const regexp = /^(\+38|8)?0[0-9]{9}$/;



for (const t of test_data) {
  console.log(t, ' --- ', regexp.test(t));
}
```

Но `80112233445` не похоже на валидную запись украинского номера (код страны `+380`) [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Телефонный_план_нумерации_Украины#Проблемы_имплементации](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD_%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B_%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8), это очень устаревший формат записи, если от него отказаться -- регулярка упрощается:

```js
const test_data = ['0991122334', '80112233445', '+380112233445', '+38011-22-33-445', '+80112233445', '+0112233445', '380112233445', '+311111111111', '+38012345678', '+390123456789', '1234567890'];

const regexp = /^(\+38)?0[0-9]{9}$/;



for (const t of test_data) {
  console.log(t, ' --- ', regexp.test(t));
}
```

И я бы, дополнительно, проверял коды операторов [https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Коди_мобільних_операторів_України#Коди_мобільних_операторів_України](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B2_%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D0%B8#%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B2_%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D0%B8) :

```js
const test_data = ['0991122334', '80112233445', '+380112233445', '+38011-22-33-445', '+80112233445', '+0112233445', '380112233445', '+311111111111', '+38012345678', '+390123456789', '1234567890'];

const regexp = /^(\+38)?0(39|50|63|66|67|68|73|89|9[1-9])[0-9]{7}$/;



for (const t of test_data) {
  console.log(t, ' --- ', regexp.test(t));
}
```